# Fabricjs: Keep one object editable (others locked) until programmatically released

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am new to Fabricjs, but have been reading the docs, doing the tutorials.

It is a very powerful library.  I see places where I can lock objects, but what I want to do is stay on an object I select, and not release it by clicking outside its boundaries.  I am building a mobile & touch screen version and using your fingers, you tend to click outside the bounds of an object.

Basically:  select an object, be able to edit, apply properties from a palette, and have a release button, so it is not released before the user is done editing it.

You can lock single elements with:

`canvas.item(0).selectable = false;`

But you still have the problem of losing selection on the object you are trying to edit should you click outside its bounds.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would just need to prevent deselection of object by selecting it back again when it's deselected. This can be done via events in Fabric:

```
var selectedObject;

canvas.on('object:selected', function(options) {
  selectedObject = options.target;
});

canvas.on('selection:cleared', function() {
  canvas.setActiveObject(selectedObject);
});
```

I made a simple example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/zCwHT/1/)) to demonstrate this.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for and very clever.  didn't think about it like that.  I will expand it to keep it on the first object selected, but a great start.  Thank you!

Comment: fiddle is removed